# How I can deal with the problem of deployed spring cloud application in docker accessing shared files write and read?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud

I deployed spring cloud application in docker.The spring cloud application use accessing picture file.When I deployed spring cloud application in docker by dockerfile. In a local development environment，I can access the picture file.When I deployed the application in docker,it cast bug.It shows that the spring cloud application not find the file on the host computer. What do I need to deal with the problem?

I have tried to copy the host computer picture file to docker volumne path. But it can not work.

My host computer of picture file path in my application yml file is like this.

```
originImgPath: /tmp/tcps/klanalyze/originImg
captchaImgPath: /tmp/tcps/klanalyze/captchaImg
```

The picture saved on the host computer path is like this.

```
/tmp/tcps/klanalyze/originImg
/tmp/tcps/klanalyze/captchaImg
```

My docker file by package is like this.

```
FROM jdk-8u191:20190321

MAINTAINER beigai_liyang

VOLUME /tmp

ADD  target/klanalyze-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app.jar" ]
```

My code is like this.

```
//read yml setting
@Autowired
private GatewayProperty gatewayProperty;

public void loadPicture(){
   ……
   //load file
   File file = new File(gatewayProperty.getOriginImgPath());
   ……
}
```

My docker version is 17.12.1-ce.

My spring cloud version is Finchley.SR1.

My Spring boot version is 2.0.3.RELEASE.

My host computer is cent-os 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need use the -v to mount your host direct to /tmp volume.

docker run  -v /tmp:/tmp  image_name

Concerns:

1. Not very make sense about "copy the host computer picture file to docker volumne path"
2. Past your docker run command here, so we could see how you run the container

Comment: Thanks,todaynowork. I deal with the problem as you method.It works.